# Error: Failed to read Ingress '/' because: the server could not find the requested resource (get ingresses.extensions

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

Hi I keep getting the below error no mater how I set up my ingress with alb controller for AWS, running on Kubernetes 1.22

```
Error: Failed to read Ingress '/' because: the server could not find the requested resource (get ingresses.extensions my-ingress)
  on .terraform/modules/service/kubernetes.tf line 144, in data "kubernetes_ingress" "sticky_ingresses":
 144: data "kubernetes_ingress" "sticky_ingresses" {
```

My ingress looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=60
    # SSL Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[ { "HTTPS": 443 }, { "HTTP": 80 } ]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: my:arn
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
    # SSL Redirect Setting
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    # Tags
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: 'some_tags=tags'
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-ingress-ui
                port: 
                  number: 443
```

Specific block where error is coming from

```
data "kubernetes_ingress" "sticky_ingresses" {
  provider = kubernetes.local

  for_each = local.present && !local.service.maintenance ? local.service.sticky_services : {}

  metadata {
    name = each.value
    namespace = local.app_namespace
  }
}
```

there are no errors in the controller, the service is running, the ingress is up and load balancer is present.
What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't the data source be `kubernetes_ingress_v1`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/ingress_v1?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, just tried running it "The provider provider.kubernetes.local does not support data source
"kubernetes_ingress_v1"."

Comment: Is this a third party provider? We need to know what custom provider this is if it is not the official one.

Comment: Thank you Matt and Marko, your comments were correct, I was using a custom provider instead of the official one, fixed by replacing provider and using kubernetes_ingress_v1

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Marko E, The data source should be `kubernetes_ingress_v1` which is the offical one .

> Ingress is a collection of rules that allow inbound connections to
> reach the endpoints defined by a backend. An Ingress can be configured
> to give services externally-reachable urls, load balance traffic,
> terminate SSL, offer name based virtual hosting etc. This data source
> allows you to pull data about such ingress.

Refer to the [document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/ingress_v1) for more infromation.